# How to prevent ethernet issues after command line shutdown in CentOS7?

Tags: networking, centos, redhat, centos7, ethernet

I'm running into a frustrating issue with a system running CentOS7. There's an Intel NIC (Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev31)) which, when working, provides a 1000Mb/s connection. When the system is shut down through command line (`sudo shutdown -h now`), the ethernet connection will no longer work upon the next boot.

Shutting the system down with the physical power button or GNOME GUI power button does not cause the same problem. Also, if the AC power supply is unplugged after command line shutdown, ethernet works fine upon next boot. So the ONLY time that this issue occurs is after command line shutdown.

The connection can be restored by unplugging the ethernet cable and plugging it back in while the system is running. It cannot be restored by restarting the NetworkManager service, nor by bringing the interface down with `ip link set enp0s31f6 down` and back up with `ip link set enp0s31f6 up`. I've messed with DHCP settings, both automatic and manual, to no avail. I've tried removing the interface from the PCI bus and rescanning, which also doesn't work. It seems that the only current solution is to physically unplug a cable.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I've tried just about everything I've found from similar questions but no luck yet.

Comment: What does `ip link` show after booting from `shutdown -h`?

Comment: @vidarlo `ip link` shows identical output after booting from shutdown -h (ethernet not working) and after booting from physical button shutdown (ethernet working): 

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:64:34:4c:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff